# Sending file by reference to a remote server?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Trying to either send a file by reference or somehow append a file on a remote server.

Using scp which just sends a copy of the file right now. My code doesn't make sense since I'm sending a copy of a file, but I can't do anything with it, because it doesn't change the original file.

```
while read p;do
    scp sample_file.txt $p"./home/user"
    #Log onto remote server
    #Get last entry of directory and put it in sample_file.txt
done <usernames_list.txt
```

Basically I want list_of_stuff.txt to look like

```
entry1
entry2
entry3
entry4
...etc
```

Does anyone know how to send the actual file (instead of scp which just sends a secure copy) to a remote server in UNIX?  Or does anyone know how to append on a remote server?

Comment: What do you mean by "send the actual file instead of ... a secure copy"?

Comment: What do the lines in usernames_list.txt look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sound of things, you don't need to copy the file to the remote server at all! You only need the output from running some commands on that server to append it to a file, so you can do that locally by piping the output from `ssh`:

```
while read p; do
    ssh $p "get_last_entry_of_directory" >> sample_file.txt
done < usernames_list.txt
```

I've dummied out the command `get_last_entry_of_directory` because I'm not sure what's supposed to be involved there.